# pdf file not showing all the pages in uiwebview in ios using objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, uiwebview

[image]Pdf file not showing all the pages in iPad apps out of 5 page it is showing only 3 when scrolling up. Remaining 2 page not showing but it showing empty screen. After using zoom or un-zoom using pinch all the pages we can able to view.

I don't know why at first time not loading all the 5 page.

I have used UIWebview to read the pdf file.

Comment: @OlSen I am not clear. could you please explain in detail about the first point in above.

Comment: @OlSen I have added image of pdf in top the third it showing then page 4 and 5 not showing in out of 5 pages. I need solution to show all the 5 pages. In code UIScrollview frame assigned to uiwebview in dynamically

Comment: broken pdf code. Consider parsing your pdf content manually to check.

Comment: @OlSen same pdf is when i added and parsing it the result is same. But when i am creating the separate project without scrollview it is working. I dont know the exact problem. I can say that Pdf is not broken

Comment: Then maybe your question was wrong. Because then it seems to be scrollview issue.

Comment: @OlSen Yes it is a scrollview issue. when i increase the zoomscall value little bit all the pdf page is showing. but now the scroll view not fitting fitting in horizontal and vertical.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, UIWebView is deprecated. It is better to update your app to use WKWebView instead and try again. You can also use below method to load from the fileURL using WKWebView

```
- loadFileURL:allowingReadAccessToURL:
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: @OlSen Yes, with out any changes its showing sometime without any changes. Just do the pinch zoom it will show.